# node-gcm : TypeError: gcm.Message is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error when i try to use node-gcm in my code. I have included it as per standard methods require('node-gcm')

```
var message = new gcm.Message();
              ^
TypeError: gcm.Message is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/parashar/Downloads/opentsdb.js:13:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this issue](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/249), it may be that an alpha version of `node-gcm` was mistakenly published as being the latest stable one.

Until that's fixed, you can try this to get your code working again:

```
npm install node-gcm@0
```

**EDIT**: [the issue should be fixed now](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/249#issuecomment-225453234).